# Do bonuses provided by city buildings transfer with your hero to the next scenario mission?

Tags: heroes-of-might-and-magic-3, hmm-chronicles

Some cities allow you to construct buildings which provide a buff to any hero that visits that city. Do these bonuses transfer with your hero to later missions, or can I avoid hitting these up if I'm close to completing the mission if they don't transfer?

**NB** This is actually Heroes Chronicles but I'ven't enough rep to create the new tag.

Example

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the modifier from Wall of Knowledge, Order of Fire, Hall of Valhalla, and Warlord's Cage is permanent.